# Relation Calculus representation for a query

Tags: relational-database

I have the relation tables as :
**DRINKS (PERSON,COFFEE)
HAS_BEAN (COFFEE,BEAN_NAME)
BEAN (BEAN_NAME, FROM_LOCATION)**

Using Relational Calculus to represent the queries:

a) Which locations contribute a bean to the coffee named “Black”?

**My Solution :** {B.Location | B ∈ Beans ∧ HB ∈ Has_Bean ∧ HB.Coffee=”Black” ∧ HB.Bean_Name=B.Bean_Name }

b) Who has never tried a coffee containing a bean from the location “Canada”?

**My Solution :**  {D.Drinker | D ∈ Drinker ∧ B ∈ Beans ∧ HB ∈ Has_Bean ∧ B.From_Location=”Canada” ∧ HB.Bean_Name = B.Bean_Name ∧ D.Coffee != HB.Coffee }

c) Which people drink all of the coffees containing the bean “Mocha”?

**My Solution:** { D.Drinker | D ∈ Drinker ∧ HB ∈ Has_Bean ∧ B.Bean_Name=”Mocha” ∧ D.Coffee = HB.Coffee}

Using Relational Algebra to represent the queries:

a)  Which beans are in the coffee named “Mocha”?

**My Solution:** ΠBean_Name (σCoffee=”Mocha” (HAS_BEAN))

b) Which people drink a coffee that contains the “Bourbon” coffee bean?

**My Solution:**  ΠPersons (σD.Coffee=HB.Coffee ^ HB.Bean_Name=”Bourbon” (DRINKER*HAS_BEAN))

c) Who has never drunk a coffee containing a bean from the location “Colombia”?

**My Solution:**

RB1<- ΠHB.Coffee ( σHB.Bean=B.Bean ^ B.Location=”Colombia” (HAS_BEAN*BEAN))

ΠPersons (σD.Coffee != RB1.Coffee (DRINKER*RB1))

Am I correct ? or am I missing any cases ?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)
 [What is the policy here on homework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18242/266284)
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] PS  There are many versions of relational calculus. Give a definition & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Calculus expressions form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. Please show what parts you are able to do. Explain re being stuck.

Comment: Please before posting look at the formatted version of your post. Please read the edit help re block & inline formating for code & quotes & re line breaks. Please ask just 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Comment: You added code you wrote, but you didn't accomplish anything else from my comments. (So why did you comment to say you edited?) (Rhetorical.) PS Re "is this right": Explain why your code is a solution. Otherwise if it has an error we can't address why you went wrong. Also, yes/no Q&A are not useful. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.